# Is is necessary to include computer code into thesis?

Tags: thesis, code

During my research, I have developed some computer codes to optimize the coefficients of theoretical equations against the experimental data. The computer codes was developed to make things easier through automation which I would otherwise need to do it manually (rather painstakingly).

Do I need to include the codes that I have developed in my thesis, or it is just sufficient to provide an executable (.exe) in a disc?

Comment: What's a disc??

Comment: Related: [*When is it useful to include the code in a thesis?*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37744/when-is-it-useful-to-include-the-code-in-a-thesis)

Comment: @DaveClarke: Various universities require handing in all code created for the thesis on a CD or DVD, along with the printed document, for archiving purposes. (The actual code might have been stored in a VCS, where it might be further extended in the future, but the version on the CD is the one "on file" as the unmodified state at the end of the thesis.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same situation with the completion of my thesis.

The first thing I did was to consult with my supervisor - seek your supervisor's advice - particularly if they have supervised someone doing similar before.

What I ended up doing (in my successfully completed thesis) was to include pseudocode and explanations of that pseudocode in the context of the experimental data (and with any theoretical background also). I was advised and did put the .exe in a CD in the back of the thesis.

Additionally, I published papers about the program and made reference to them in the thesis.

Another option is to upload the code in an online code repository (e.g. [GitHub](https://github.com/)), only if there is no issues with sharing the code.

(Note: where I am, research theses are peer-reviewed for assessment)

Answer (score 0):

#### In general:

If the program is really just to ease some work you might as well have performed manually, it’s not necessary; you do not even have to supply the software on a disc or otherwise. I have yet to see a paper or thesis that includes every code used in the process (and if there were some, who would want to read that). The general idea is that your scientific work is creating concepts and theories or translating them to a given problem and such programs exist only to alleviate the inevitable legwork.

As soon as there is any manual step involved in evaluating your work, it’s impossible to completely verify your work without reproducing it. If you had performed this task manually, you wouldn’t have yourself videotaped while doing it and appended the result to your thesis, would you?

Of course, if the program is central to your work or involves non-trivial steps, doing something between outlining the algorithm or actually appending the source code would be appropriate and sharing the program may help others in your field (and attract people to your work). But this doesn’t seem to be the case here.

#### In special:

Your advisor or unversity may think differently about this and their opinion counts. Ask them or read their guidelines, respectively.

Comment: "I have yet to see a paper or thesis that includes every code used in the process" - I have seen many thesis CDs that included everything used during the thesis (this includes document sources and presentation slides, but also sources of custom software developed for the thesis, central or supporting, build scripts, in Eclipse-based projects sometimes also a pre-configured IDE, etc.). In particular, I generally ask my students to put the whole contents of their VCS onto the CD. No-one reads that "for fun", but it can always be helpful for future students who want to apply similar procedures.

Comment: Also, concerning "The general idea is that your scientific work is creating concepts and theories and such code exists only to alleviate the legwork." - this statement probably assumes that the OP is talking about a PhD thesis (and even that is not *limited* to only showing conceptual work), rather than e.g. a Master thesis, which is not currently stated in the question.

Comment: If I were to include "everything used during the thesis" I would need several thousand CDs. I currently have ~2.5 terabytes of data generated so far.

Comment: As for including the .exe file: it's much better to also include the source code, since the .exe file may not run correctly on a different computer, may not run correctly in a few years time on a new Windows version, and it will definitely not run on OSX or Linux.

Comment: @semi-extrinsic: Nitpick: "it will definitely not run on OSX or Linux." - except if it is a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) `.exe` file, or maybe if something like Wine is used.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the CLI implementation for Linux ceased development in 2007 and the project was disbanded in 2012. Also, I've never heard of such a thing before, so I don't think it's very common. Maybe better examples would be Python or Matlab scripts?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: We do not have thesis CDs; we have a group versioning system. Handing in a CD with a thesis is not even considered in the regulations, IIRC. (AIso, just dumping everything on a CD is certainly more easy than carefully selecting and documenting the actually relevant stuff.)

Comment: @semi-extrinsic: The [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/) is alive and kicking, its latest release is from September 2015.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: *this statement probably assumes that the OP is talking about a PhD thesis* – No. It certainly depends on where you draw the line be legwork and creative work, but haven’t heard of a degree being awarded for pure brainless legwork (outside of medicine). The whole point of the degree is to show that you can perform scientific work (under supervison for some degrees) – not that you are capable of programming or calculating. Anyway, I expanded the respective statement a little.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper could you link to an example of such a CLI .exe and how to run it on Linux? This sounds interesting.

Comment: @semi-extrinsic and O.R.Mapper: Can you please take that discussion to chat?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: The purpose of Bachelor and Master theses is to show that the candidate can solve a typical technical problem from their future profession with their professional skills. To large extents, this means the selection and application of well-known concepts. From a scientific point of view, this is pure legwork (because there is no conceptual novelty), but from a (w.l.o.g.) software development point of view, this is highly creative. Hence, it is crucial to show such programming (high and low level) skills in Bachelor and Master theses, in order to prove the student's technical skills.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: *The purpose of Bachelor and Master theses is to show that the candidate can solve a typical technical problem from their future profession with their professional skills* – It certainly isn’t in my field. But even then, solving the problem happens on a totally different level than programming – unless maybe if your field is computer science or related, but that’s what the third paragraph is for and very unlikely to be the case here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Indeed, my field is computer science (therefore I wrote "w.l.o.g.", but maybe not in the optimal place). I admit, though, that I maybe unreasonably assumed that if, as the OP describes, they wrote a program to automate some tedious process that *could* otherwise be done manually, they probably are in CS, too - in my personal experience, most people outside of CS will rather do something manually for some reason, rather than relying on the beauty of a program that does it all for you (and spending the time to write it first!) ;) But then, if such a program or script helps do ...

Comment: ... their work more efficiently, I'd argue that writing such programs *is* a useful professional skill that should be shown in the thesis again. Of course, conventions between fields, also with respect to how industry-ready graduates need to be, vary greatly.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I am in group of physicists where everybody works on the computer all the time, which includes a lot of programming. If we get to know that somebody did some tedious process manually, while it could be done easily with a program, we see that this does not happen again. Yet, you hardly see pseudocode in our theses. It would be like photographing every tiny step of a lab experiment to document how you read the instruments. — I am pretty certain that if the OP were a computer scientist, they would not have described the role of their code in their thesis like this.

Comment: **Please take extended discussion to [chat].**